# How to send raw data to printer with Java

Tags: java, exception, printing, document, raw-data

I am trying to create a simple program that sends a string to a printer to print. This is what my program looks like:

```
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;

public class PrinterTest {
  public static void main (String [] args) throws PrintException {
    DocPrintJob job = null;
    PrintService[] printServices = 
    PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    System.out.println("Number of print services: " + printServices.length);
    for (PrintService printer : printServices) {
        System.out.println("Printer: " + printer.getName());
        if (printer.getName().contains("ZM400")) {
            String hello = "Hello";
            DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.STRING.TEXT_PLAIN;
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(hello, flavor, null);
            job = printer.createPrintJob();
            job.print(doc, null);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I export this as a jar file and run it on command line (Windows) using:

```
java -jar PrinterTest.jar
```

The program runs, and starts looping through all of the installed printers on the computer. But when it gets to the printer I am looking for, I then get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException: invalid flavor
  at sun.print.Win32PrintJob.print(Unknown Source)
  at PrinterTest.main(PrinterTest.java:21)
```

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong here, as the printer that I am searching for does in fact show up.

-Using the following link for reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/jpsOverview.fm4.html

-Tried changing `DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.STRING.TEXT_PLAIN` to `DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE`, but I get the error `IllegalArgumentException: data is not of declared type`.

-Tried changing `Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(hello, flavor, null)` to `Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(hello, null, null)`, but it seems like you need to add a flavor there.

-Tried changing the printer, as the original printer I was trying to call was a labeling printer, but that did not make a difference.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? What can I do to fix this code and make it print?

**UPDATE**

I got this to (somewhat) work. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;

public class PrinterTest {
  public static void main (String [] args) throws PrintException, IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the printer: ");
    String printerName = bufferedReader.readLine();
    System.out.print("Enter a short message of what you would like to print here: ");
    String printerMessage = "PRINTER MESSAGE: " + bufferedReader.readLine();
    boolean printerCheck = false;
    DocPrintJob job = null;
    PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    System.out.println("Number of print services: " + printServices.length);
    for (PrintService printer : printServices) {
        System.out.println("Printer: " + printer.getName());
        if (printer.getName().contains(printerName)) {
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(printerMessage.getBytes());
            DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(inputStream, flavor, null);
            job = printer.createPrintJob();
            job.print(doc, null);
            printerCheck = true;
        }
    }
    if (printerCheck == false) {
        System.out.println("The printer you were searching for could not be found.");
    }
  }
}
```

What I did was put the string into an input stream, and changed `DocFlavor.STRING.TEXT_PLAIN` to `DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE`.

My only hiccup now is that nothing **actually** prints unless *something else* is sent to the printer. Leaving this here for now for reference.

Comment: Way back in the dark ages, to get a printer to scroll the last page out, you had to send it an ASCII form-feed byte `0xC` (produced on a DOS terminal by typing Control-L, and usually represented `^L`).  If your printer ejects individual sheets instead of emitting an unbroken stream of green-bar fan-fold paper, this knowledge is probably not helpful... unless the printer was designed to be backward-compatible all the way back to dot-matrix serial printers.  (I would find that downright charming.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exception messages are rather helpful and should help you to find a solution.

1) First, this flavor is not supported by your printer :

```
 DocFlavor.STRING.TEXT_PLAIN;
```

This exception says it :

> Exception in thread "main" sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException: invalid
>   flavor

If you look in the source code of this constant value, you can see that it is declared as :

```
public static final STRING TEXT_PLAIN =
    new STRING ("text/plain; charset=utf-16");
```

So, the first thing you should do is checking which flavors are supported by your printer.
To render it, change the actual code :

```
if (printer.getName().contains("ZM400")) {
    String hello = "Hello";
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.STRING.TEXT_PLAIN;
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(hello, flavor, null);
    job = printer.createPrintJob();
    job.print(doc, null);
}
```

by :

```
if (printer.getName().contains("ZM400")) {
    Arrays.stream(printer.getSupportedDocFlavors()).forEach(f->System.out.println(f.getMediaType() + ":" + f.getMimeType() + ":" + f.getRepresentationClassName()));
    String hello = "Hello";
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.STRING.TEXT_PLAIN;
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(hello, flavor, null);
    job = printer.createPrintJob();
    job.print(doc, null);
}
```

With my printer, it produces the following output :

> image:image/gif:[B image:image/gif:java.io.InputStream
>
> image:image/gif:java.net.URL image:image/jpeg:[B
>
> image:image/jpeg:java.io.InputStream image:image/jpeg:java.net.URL
>
> image:image/png:[B image:image/png:java.io.InputStream
>
> image:image/png:java.net.URL
>
> application:application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref:java.awt.print.Pageable
>
> application:application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref:java.awt.print.Printable
>
> application:application/octet-stream:[B
>
> application:application/octet-stream:java.net.URL
>
> application:application/octet-stream:java.io.InputStream

You may notice the my printer doesn't support the
    `"text/plain; charset=utf-16"` flavor either.

2) By changing the flavor to `DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE`, you don't have any longer the exception related to missing support for the `DocFlavor`.
So it means that `DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE` is supported by your printer.
But you encounter another problem as the data to print doesn't match to declared type associated to `DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE` :

> IllegalArgumentException: data is not of declared type.

In `DocFlavor`, the `INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE` constant is declared in this way :

```
    public static final INPUT_STREAM AUTOSENSE =
        new INPUT_STREAM ("application/octet-stream");
```

This corresponds to the last supported flavor in the previous output :

> application:application/octet-stream:java.io.InputStream

And the problem is there :

```
String hello = "Hello";     
...
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(hello, flavor, null);
```

you don't have pass a `InputStream` but a `String`.

You can for example provide an `InputStream` in this way:

```
String hello = "Hello";     
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(new ByteArrayInputStream(hello.getBytes()),
                         flavor, null);
```

Or you could also use this flavor :

> application:application/octet-stream:[B

as you have not an `InputStream` but a `String` as input :

Here is the flavor constant to use :

```
DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE
```

You could also use it in this way :

```
String hello = "Hello";     
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(hello.getBytes(), flavor, null);
```